# How to delete entire JSON entry if the value is not found in other keys using jq in Powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, jq

```
{
    "openapi": "3.0.1",
    "paths": {
        "/api/car": {
            "summary": "Something about Duration"
        },
        "/api/plane": {
            "summary": "Something about Duration"
        }
    },
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Duration": {
                "enum": [
                    "OneMonth",
                    "ThreeMonth"
                ]
            },
            "Apple": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "flaggedDataCount": {
                        "type": "integer",
                        "description": "someting",
                        "format": "int32"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a JSON entry above.
I want to delete any JSON entry in `schemas`, which is not found in `paths` values recursively.

For example, `Duration` is found in the values at `paths`, but not for `Apple`.

So `Apple` entry should be deleted from the JSON file.

How do I do it with `jq` in `Powershell`?

I have thought of the codes below but I do not know:

- walk from components
- count the key value in the rest of JSON file at the `test`

`walk(if type == "object????" then with_entries(select(.key | test("?????") | not)) else . end)`

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the relevance of the `with_entries(select(...))` idiom:

```
[.paths[].summary] as $texts
| .components.schemas |=
    with_entries( select( .key as $key | any($texts[]; index($key) )))
```

Comment: Sorry I did not specify my question clearly. How do I change `[.paths[].summary]` so `$texts` would get not only `summary` but also other values nested in the `paths`?

Comment: Perhaps `[.paths[] | .. | strings] as $texts` will do?  Or do you want the key names to be included as well?