# Why jq does not compile when I pass a Powershell variable?

Tags: json, powershell, jq

Inspired by the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67626589/10718164), I want to delete any JSON entry from `components.schemas` if it is not found in the `$paths`

Here is my Powershell script with `jq`:

```
$paths = jq '.. |.\"$ref\"? | select(. != null)' $srcJson
jq '.components.schemas |= with_entries( select( .key as $key | any(${paths}[]; index($key) )))' $srcJson | Out-File $destinationJson -Encoding UTF8
```

This is a sample JSON file before changes: https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cbc78213

Then this is the expect JSON file after I run the Powershell script above: https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cb8c4b2b

Notice that the `BadSchemas` is removed from the `components.schemas`

When I run the code in PowerShell, I got error message below:

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '{', expecting IDENT or **loc** (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
> .components.schemas |= with_entries( select( .key as $key | any(${paths}[]; index($key) )))

Could anyone show me where have I done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Is $ref set to something?  The first line comes up blank for me.  What's an example json?  I know double quotes need to be backslashed.

Comment: @js2010 Here is the JSON snipper with the jq command https://jqplay.org/s/kNkA2aDWPC

Comment: Oh, the name of the property is literally `$ref`?  That's weird.

Comment: @js2010, `$ref` is automatically generated by openapi generator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Powershell [doesn't expand variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#single-and-double-quoted-strings) inside single quoted strings. If you want `${paths}` to be expanded by Powershell it will need to be in double quotes.

However, in general this isn't the best way to pass variables to `jq`. It's better to use [`--arg` and `--argjson`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Invokingjq) which respectively pass strings and json values in as jq variables.

I don't have a Windows machine to test this, but you should be able to do something like this:

```
$paths = jq '.. |.\"$ref\"? | select(. != null)' $srcJson | ConvertTo-Json
jq --argjson paths "$paths" '.components.schemas |= with_entries( select( .key as $key | any($paths[]; index($key) )))' $srcJson | Out-File $destinationJson -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: I got `invalid JSON text passed to --argjson`, unless I piped $paths to convertto-json first.  $paths didn't have to be double quoted.

Comment: Feel free to propose an edit to this answer with the correct command-line, otherwise I'll update it when I'm at a Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried breaking the strings passed to jq where you are passing an OS variable?  I've had to use this on bash for Linux to deal with complex operations.

```
$paths = jq '.. |.\"'$ref'\"? | select(. != null)' $srcJson
jq '.components.schemas |= with_entries( select( .key as $key | any('${paths}'[]; index($key) )))' $srcJson | Out-File $destinationJson -Encoding UTF8
```

I can't test this, since I don't have your variables to work with, but that should allow the command interpreter to expand the powershell variables that you pass.

Feedback on this assumption for PowerShell would be good, since I'm trying to learn PowerShell but have been coding bash or Windows CMD so far, so not sure if this approach is a good resolution.